# How to color topnav when background-color is already in use?

Tags: html, css, navbar, background-color

For some reason, `.topnav` isn't doing what it's asked. `.topnav` is supposed to be colored `#A10800`, but it's white. I have already used `background-color` to specify which color the topnav is supposed to be. What's the solution to the problem?

```css
.topnav {
  background: #A10800;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background: #D1281F;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FF837A;
  top: 100%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="index.php">NON-HOVER</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="index.php">HOVER</a>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="index.php">DROPDOWN</a></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

(hover to see elements)

Answer (score 0):

```
.topnav {
    float: left;
    background: #A10800;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 25px;  
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You put `float:left;` on both `.topnav a` and `.topnav`. niCe

I don't know why, but I'll take it

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `float` the component loses its `height:auto` property.

Either you have to get rid of the float or just add height in your `.topnav`

Something like this will work

```
.topnav {
    background: #A10800;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `div` with class `.topnav` in another `div` with class `.color`

```
.color {
    background: #A10800;
}
```

and your problem will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

When you float an element, its parent ignores its height. So `topnav` is collapsed, thus the `background-color` is not visible.
In order to fix this, you can place an element after the floated elements, which clears the floating.
You can either add an element in your HTML for that or use a pseudo-element like :after:

```
.topnav:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```